# Phpunit: how many times has a private method run?

Tags: php, phpunit

```
class TestMe
{
    private function a ($a, $b)
    {
        return $a+$b;
    }

    private function b ($a, $b)
    {
        return $a*$b;
    }

    public function serial ($a, $b)
    {
        $this->a ($a,$b);
        $this->b ($a,$b);
    }
```

and the testing:

```
public function testA()
{
    $ref = new ReflectionClass ('TestMe');
    $method = $classNameOrObject->getMethod('a');
    $method->setAccessible(true);
    $this->assertEquals (2, $method->invokeArgs (1,1));
}

public function testB()
{
    $ref = new ReflectionClass ('TestMe');
    $method = $classNameOrObject->getMethod('b');
    $method->setAccessible(true);
    $this->assertEquals (1, $method->invokeArgs (1,1));
}

public function testSerial()
{
    $sut = new TestMe();
    $sut->testB();
}
```

at `testSerial` I would want to check that `a()` and `b()` triggers once:

```
$stub = $this->getMock ('TestMe', array('a', 'b'));
$stub->expects($this->once())->method('a');
$stub->expects($this->once())->method('b');
```

which is not possible right now, because private methods are not be able to be mocked. Any idea? I can do it with the `ReflectionClass` but then it would make the original function unworkable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mock the private methods.  Don't even try to test them.  They are details of your class that you don't need to be concerned with.  All that you care about is what the public functions do.  Which in your example is really nothing (it calls two methods that return values and does nothing with them).

However suppose that the method subtracted the two values.  So the function looks like this:

```
public function serial ($a, $b)
{
    $c = $this->a ($a,$b);
    $d = $this->b ($a,$b);

    return $c - $d;
}
```

An example test might be like this:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider dataSerial
 */
public function testSerial($a, $b, $exp) {
    $sut = new TestMe();
    $this->assertEquals($exp, $sut->serial($a, $b));
}

public function dataSerial() {
    return array(
        array(
            1,
            1,
            1
        ),
        array(
            2,
            3,
            5
        ),
    )
}
```

All that I care about is what the function serial returns (or does).  I don't care about the private function.  If for some reason, you decide to remove the private functions the above test passes.  Or if extra functionality that is in `serial()` gets moved into a new private function the tests will pass.

Specifying that a private function gets called makes your test less usable and makes refactoring your code more difficult.  Refactoring shouldn't change the functionality so it shouldn't lead to failed tests.  Specifying the private methods means you have to determine whether the test failed due to removal of the private method or that you introduced a bug.

If your private functions are extremely complicated that you feel that they need to be tested alone.  This is a code smell that perhaps these methods should be extracted to their own class.